# Whats the name of the instrumental soundtrack at the start in Mardock Scramble:The First Compression?

Tags: music, mardock-scramble

As the title says what is the name/title of the instrumental song/BGM that is played during the first 4 minutes of the start of the anime movie *Mardock Scramble: The First Compression*?

Answer (score 2):

The track that starts at 55 seconds into the movie and ends with the title card at 3:16 is called "*Balot -The little girl in the huge city-*".

It's the second track on the [official soundtrack for the first movie](http://vgmdb.net/album/20395) and composed by [Conish (コーニッシュ)](http://www.conisch.com/www_top.html). (The first track on the OST is the one they used for the trailer)